# Do bindings nested inside of a lazy one-time ng-repeat binding bind just once?

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

My understand is that in the following code, both bindings will ***[lazily bind only once](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/cee429f0aaebf32ef1c9aedd8447a48f163dd0a4)***:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{::item.name}}</li>
```

However, in the following case **will `{{item.name}}` be updated every digest?**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{item.name}}</li>
```

And **how does one-time binding effect nested `ng-repeat`s** ?

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ::items">
  <span ng-repeat="thing in item.things">{{thing.name}}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

### Scenario 1:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{::item.name}}</li>
```

Both expressions will be one-time bound. Adding an item or changing an existing item's name will not be reflected.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/53r8FCmcNK4MmM6Uzxp2?p=preview

### Scenario 2:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{item.name}}</li>
```

First expression will be one-time bound. Adding an item will not be reflected. Changing an existing item's name will be reflected.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/52wTEb8ze2FKRDDcS9Ow?p=preview

### Scenario 3:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ::items">
  <span ng-repeat="thing in item.things">{{thing.name}}</span>
</li>
```

First expression will be one-time bound. Adding new item will not be reflected. Adding a new thing and changing existing thing's name will be reflected.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/HkObhkJtUnFEHBAzFUmN?p=preview

Comment: Can we do this? - ```<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{::item.name}}</li>```

Comment: @Chipmunk Yes. Just play with the Plnkr demo that tasseKATT provided to see for yourself.