# AngularJS - Upgrading v1.2.5 to 1.3 to use bind once

Tags: angularjs, optimization, data-binding, angularjs-scope, bindonce

I am trying to improve the performance of my ng-repeat's. I have upgraded my project to use library v1.3.0 (main lib and route).

I am trying to use the bind once as here: [Do bindings nested inside of a lazy one-time ng-repeat binding bind just once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903389/do-bindings-nested-inside-of-a-lazy-one-time-ng-repeat-binding-bind-just-once)

However, when i add :: to my ng-repeat, the list is not populated:

```
<li ng-repeat="info in Profile.ChangeInfo">                 
    <p> {[{info.Message}]} </p>
</li>
```

The above works.

The below fails:

```
<li ng-repeat="info in ::Profile.ChangeInfo">                   
    <p> {[{::info.Message}]} </p>
</li>
```

Error i see is:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.9/$parse/syntax?p0=%3A&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=1&p3=%3A%3AProfile.ChangeInfo&p4=%3A%3AProfile.ChangeInfo
```

---

**UPDATE**
Upgraded to beta 16, and now seeing this error in IE8:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Fri, 15 Aug 2014 12:01:03 UTC

```
Message: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
Object doesn't support this property or method
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=Object%20doesn't%20support%20this%20property%20or%20method
Line: 3982
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://local host:1010/js/vendor/angular.js
```

Comment: Angular 1.3 dropped IE8 support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bindonce syntax `::` has been [introduced](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/86d55c1ded21a5be6091344493d70c6dc4194e43) since angularjs version 1.3.0-beta.16

You have to upgrade angularjs to version 1.3.0-beta.16 or newer.

Comment: can now see the list, but IE8 no longer loads the page.

Comment: AngularJS v1.3.x already dropped support for IE8, not sure if it's relate to your issue. Is there any error in the console?

Comment: displaying the error in my Update post. Beta 8 is working fine in IE8

Comment: @OamPsy If you really need to support IE8, it might be better to stick with angularjs `1.2.x`. And if you would like to use the bindonce feature, you could use something like this 3rd party module https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

Answer (score 2):

please see here sample demo http://jsbin.com/wimon/2/edit

Use the latest angularjs beta

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Remove square bracket

```
<li ng-repeat="info in ::Profile.ChangeInfo">                   
    <p> {{::info.Message}} </p>
</li>
```

Comment: can now see the list, but IE8 no longer loads the page.

Comment: angular 1.3 no supporting IE8 http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/12/angularjs-13-new-release-approaches.html

Comment: i know this, Beta 8 is working fine in IE8... Beta 16/17/18 is not.

Comment: @OamPsy sorry but don't understand your question then

Comment: You have :: before Profile here but not in jsbin, which is correct?

Comment: @Neil that depends if you want bind ones your array or object in array only please see here http://jsbin.com/dujijuxeju/1/edit