# Closing modal in Angular UI Bootstrap while erasing array of 1000 items, takes a significant time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-bindings

I've an Angular application where I pass an empty array to [Angular-UI Bootstrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). Depends on user choice it may be filled or not with items, up to 1000 objects. All them I display in a list with `ng-repeat`. All items in a list are pre-generated, so I can't retrieve them asynchronously for example by using plugin like [smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/). 
When user press **ok** button all generated values returned to `controller` from which it was called. Technically all them already there because I pass `$scope.items` by reference:

```
resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
```

But when I press **cancel** button I'm erasing all items in an array by invoking `$scope.items.length=0;` My problem that it takes a while. In my plunker example below it's barely noticeable but noticeable but in my actual application it's much more noticeable and unacceptable.

My guess that It's due to Angular's two-way binding, it takes a time to clean all watchers but I don't know how to solve this issue, if it can be solved.

My MCVE at plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/JwanDxBzh3a7ilEX58z8?p=preview

**UPDATE**: Tried to use one-time binging, plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PjzHRYiuXFHE1M1Pap6U?p=preview

```
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a href="#"> {{ ::item | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</a>
            </li>
```

as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791503/947111 it didn't help.

Comment: Are you doing something more complicated than this in your real modal? Like for instance, doing a $watch inside a directive that's watching each item?

Comment: No, but I've solved my issue. I've used one-time binding in a wrong way with `ng-repeat`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was right and I was almost there with Angular's `one-time binding` I just used it in a wrong place, and should be used in a `ng-repeat` in a such way:

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in ::items">
                    <a href="#"> {{::item | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</a>
                </li>
```

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23903690/947111

Working plunker located here: http://plnkr.co/edit/XWi6Z0eCXveV58WJfpo6?p=preview