# Remove element from ng-repeat but, keep its HTML in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an array `badge = [{'name':'abc', 'flag': true}, {'name':'cde', 'flag': false}, {'name':'def', 'flag': true} ]`

used it with `ng-repeat` and dom is created on browser. Now i need to delete element having flag `false` from array but, keep the HTML (created by ng-repeat) entact in browser.

Comment: Copy that array into another one and do ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [**`filter`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

function HelloCntl($scope) {
  $scope.badge = [{
    'name': 'abc',
    'flag': true
  }, {
    'name': 'cde',
    'flag': false
  }, {
    'name': 'def',
    'flag': true
  }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng:app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="b in badge | filter:{flag:true}">
        <span>{{b.name}}</span>
        <span>{{b.flag}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to keep the element visible and just disable it.

Comment: I think you're missing the point, too bad because nice code snippet! 
edit - got short-circuited by atulquest 8)

Comment: What ? Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

Use one time binding. So that when you change model then DOM will not be reflected again after first time load.

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="b in ::badge">
        <span>{{b.name}}</span>
        <span>{{b.flag}}</span>
      </li>
</ul>
```

For disabling the deleted things, use **`ng-class`** with normal two way binding.

For one time binding please google, or refer [Do bindings nested inside of a lazy one-time ng-repeat binding bind just once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903389/do-bindings-nested-inside-of-a-lazy-one-time-ng-repeat-binding-bind-just-once)

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML use something like:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in badge">
  <li ng-show="value.flag">{{value.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Using ng-if will remove the element from the DOM. Using ng-show will just hide it from the DOM (using ng-hidden class).

Answer (score 0):

You could put two ng-repeats next to each other and have the second one initially empty and your first one as you show it. Then you can delete it from the first array and put it in the second one.

This way you can remove the element, but still keep it in the DOM.